# How to add database system to WebGL application

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database, opengl-es

I'm currently working on a WebGL sketch drawing project where users can draw arbitrary objects on an html canvas. The javascript libraries and files are all stored on a node.js server which is currently being started up locally every time the software has to be run. Essentially all of the functionality for saving all of the drawn objects on the page has been implemented where the drawings are being written as JSON objects, but the next step is to persist these objects to a database where they can be mapped to a user id. I will also need to implement a login system where users will login and be able to select previously drawn objects to edit from the database.

If this was just a normal website, I would probably just use express.js or something similar, but as the views are essentially rendered entirely in WebGL, I wouldn't think that frameworks would work well with this construct.

**Given that I currently just need to create a login system and implement a feature for persisting the JSON object to the DB, are there any frameworks or existing software that accommodates the specified needs of the system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to authentication, I would recommend taking a look at [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and using existing identity providers (e.g. [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login), etc). You can still retain profiles for your users but you don't have to deal with all of the intricacies of authentication, authorization, security, etc.

There are a ton of JavaScript libraries out there for handling OAuth/OAuth2 interactions. Some even have built-in identity providers. Here are a couple links that returned all sorts of potentially useful libraries:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=oauth2
https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20oauth2%20library

As for a database, you have a lot of options for storing raw JSON. Some that I've used recently for my JavaScript projects are [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), and [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/). You can find well written JS libraries for interacting with any of those.

Another thing to think about is if you want to install the database on your server or use a hosted solution such as [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) or [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) (available from Amazon).

Regardless of the exact authentication and persistence options you choose you will likely use a pattern similar to this:

- Your Node.js server is deployed somewhere accessible on the internet, where it exposes the endpoints for your WebGL application, authentication, and saving/loading sketches.
- When the user navigates to the WebGL application endpoint on your Node.js server they are required to authenticate (which will utilize your authentication endpoints on the Node.js server).
- When the user requests a "save" in your WebGL application you will submit the JSON representation of their sketch (and their authorization token) to the "save" endpoint of your Node.js server.
- This "save" endpoint validates the user's authorization token and inserts the JSON into whatever database you've chosen.
- The "load" endpoint works just like the "save" endpoint but in reverse. The user asks for a specific sketch. The identity of the sketch (id, name, etc) is sent along with their authorization token. The "load" endpoint on your Node.js server validates their authorization token and then queries the database for the sketch.

The key pattern to notice here is that users don't send requests to your database directly. Your WebGL application should communicate back to your Node.js server and **it** should commmunicate with your database. This is essential for controlling security, performance, and future updates.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of where to go next.

---

**EDIT based on comments:**

I searched around for a Node.js + PostgreSQL guide but didn't find anything I would feel comfortable recommending. I did find this JS library though, which I would check out:

https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise

For MongoDB I would just use their official guide:

https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/introduction/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! With regards to installing one of the main DBMS's on the node server, which would you recommend? I was leaning towards postgres as I have experience using it and I've also heard mixed reviews about Mongo. I looked for tutorials online for setting up either of those DBMS's with a node server and haven't found much except for how to use the package manager to install postgres. Do you have any good resources for getting up and running?

Comment: To be honest, any of them will work just fine. I use PostgreSQL because it is what I am most familiar with. Anecdotally we use MongoDB at work to store live flight information, where it receives millions of transactions (reads and writes) a day and it works fine. I've updated my answer to include some further reading.

Comment: When you say that you use PostgreSQL, do you mean on node.js servers or just in general?

Comment: I've used it as the storage mechanism for Node.js applications but I also use it for other projects completely unrelated to Node.js and JavaScript.

Comment: Oh ok, and so I'm assuming that you would be using some framework or stack that connects node withe postgreSQL.

Comment: For example that pg-promise library I linked in my answer can be used within a Node.js application. It provides a client that you use to connect to any (local or remote) PostgreSQL instance via a driver (included with the library). There aren't a lot of moving parts actually.